# Two word compounds ( type file or file type )

Tags: word-usage, word-order, compounds, compound-nouns

I'm looking for the rule for compound nouns. Do I say:

- phone number or number phone
- file type or type file
- bag school or school bag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format is `<adjective><noun>` so in "school bag", we are talking about the bag (which is used in school). "Bag school" we are talking about a school.

Could be even `<adjective1><adjective2><noun>` and even more stacked adjectives, but last one is the noun.

Answer (score 10):

the rule for word order in this case is

> {type}{thing}

so, to take your examples in order:

> phone number

the thing that you have (say 01234 567890) is a number. What type of number is it? it's a phone number.

> file type

a bit more abstract, what we have is a type (say, .doc). What sort of type is it? it's a file type.

> school bag

the thing here is a bag. It's a bag you take to school, so it's a school bag.

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers say, the general rule is adjective before noun
(or, more generally, the noun comes after the word describing it<sup>1</sup>),
so your specific phrases should be “phone number”, “file type”,
and “school bag”. 
A “bag school” would be a school that taught something about bags. 
It sounds boring to me,
but it might be a job prerequisite for baggage handlers
(e.g., for hotels and airports) or grocery store clerks.

To give a perhaps slightly more mundane example,
a “clown class” would be a course of education in how to be a clown
(I’ve never heard of such a thing, but they probably exist),
whereas a “class clown” is a person who behaves in a clown-like way
while in class (and this is a common idiom).

This is the *general* (99%) rule. 
See [Why do some adjectives follow the nouns they modify?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/42319/26083) for a discussion. 
It references [the Wikipedia article on Postpositive adjectives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postpositive_adjective),
which says that the adjective-after-noun structure

- is normal in some non-English languages,
- is rarely used in modern English: for example, “attorney general”, “heir apparent”, “professor emeritus”, “proof positive”, “time immemorial”, “Amnesty International” (and other names), “code red”, “devil incarnate”, and “chicken supreme”.

_________
<sup>1</sup> As the other answers *don’t* point out,
your question is interesting because it’s not about adjective+noun phrases;
it’s about *two-noun* phrases. 
But the guidance is the same:
the word for the *thing* that you’re talking about comes last
(99% of the time).  For example, “water faucet” is plumbing,
but “tap water” is the liquid that comes out of it.